# Add column script not working correctly in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have some trouble in Magento sql updating table. I create extension and I would like to add some new columns to existing table 'customer_group'.

```
<modules>
    <Module_Name>
        <module>1.0.0</module>
    </Module_Name>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <module_name>
            <class>Module_Name_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>module_name_resource</resourceModel>
        </module_name>

        <module_name_resource>
            <class>Module_Name_Model_Resource</class>
        </module_name_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <module_name_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Module_Name</module>
                <class>Module_Name_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </module_name_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
```

In sql/module_name_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php I have this code:

```
$installer = $this;
$connection = $installer->getConnection();

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('customer/customer_group'), 'column_one', array(
        'TYPE' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'NULLABLE' => false,
        'COMMENT' => 'Column One'
    ))
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('customer/customer_group'), 'column_two', array(
        'TYPE' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'NULLABLE' => false,
        'COMMENT' => 'Column Two'
    ));

$installer->endSetup();
```

But when I refresh Magento frontend page I didn't saw in **core_resources** table any changes and in **customer_group** these two columns didn't exist. 
What I do wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `<depends>
                <Mage_Customer />
            </depends>` in your pp/etc/modules/Your.xml file

Comment: I've tried now `<modules>
        <Module_Name>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Shipping />
                <Mage_Customer />
            </depends>
        </Module_Name>
    </modules>` don't working

Comment: Are you sure it's being executed? Delete the entry for `module_name_setup` in `core_resources` table, put a `die('hello')` on the first line of your install script, clear cache and refresh the page. If you don't see the "hello", is something wrong with the config. I hope it helps!

Comment: Did you declare your module in `app/etc/modules/Module_Name.xml`?

Comment: to **Javier** - I haven't **module_name_setup** in **core_resources**, because this script don't working. But extension is working correctly

Comment: to **Steve** - yes, I declare module in this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve this bug. I forgot to set version in **app/etc/Module_Name.xml**, it should be

```
<modules>
    <Module_Name>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Shipping/>
        </depends>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Module_Name>
</modules>
```

and in **config.xml** version should be set too

Comment: Note that in your question, you have the version number inside the "module" tag: `<module>1.0.0</module>` (instead of "version"). I think that was the issue because you can specify the version either on the etc/modules/Module_Name.xml or on the etc/config.xml and both should work.

Comment: yes, you right. It's my mistake. I forgot about **app/etc/Module_Name** version

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this is how I do a install script:

Place the install script at:

```
Company/Module/sql/your_module_setup/install-1.0.0.0.php
```

And in the etc/config.xml of the module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <your_module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Company_Module</module>
                    <class>Company_Module_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </your_module_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then make create the file Company/Module/Model/Resource/Setup.php:

```
<?php
class Company_Module_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup
{
}
```